# Dell PowerEdge R300 does not recognize SATA RAID controller anymore

Tags: dell

I bought a R300, and I had it going to the boot menu trying to play around with boot order, etc. I left it there for a week, and when I got back to working on the machine, I rebooted it. Afterward, the machine no longer probes/detects the on board, built-in SATA RAID controller (Perc6i I think) anymore. I definitely can see the controller before, but now I don't see it, and the system complains there is no boot device. The drive light is on.

Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't show up during the POST, I would try reseating the controller and drive connections (if applicable).

If that doesn't work, someone or something probably let the magic smoke out of it.  Call Dell as a warrantee call.

Answer (score 0):

Without having one handy to look at, try this: When the machine boots up access the BIOS settings and look for a setting to change the controller from SCSI to RAID mode. If it's not in the BIOS settings it will be in the controller settings (CTRL-M?).